# jQuery Nested li, get ID

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a problem with nested li's and grabbing the ID of the element clicked.

Assume this is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li id="folderLink_1">Link 1</li>
    <li id="folderLink_2">Link 2
        <ul>
            <li id="folderLink_3">Link 2.1</li>
            <li id="folderLink_4">Link 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I also have this jQuery:

```
$('[id^=folderLink_]').live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

When I click on Link 1, I just get the one ID alerted to me, folderLink_1.
However when I click on link 2.1, not only do I get folderLink_3, but also folderLink_2 one after another.

**I've looked around, and tried using the event.stopPropagation(), however this stops subsequent actions from taking place too which are needed.**

The idea is, the folders act as an image library folder structure. When you click a folder, it saves the ID of that folder to a JS variable. When a folder with images contained within it is clicked, ajax retrieves a URL, using the ID in the querystring.

I have tried wrapping the text within the LI around a span, however that I have images around the text which need to act in the same way (if clicked save the ID).

I have attached images for better help.

[image: Step One: Click the menu item anywhere in the red section]
[image: Step Two: When the link is clicked, the ID of that folder is saved, and another menu slides right]
[image: Step Three: The new menu slides into where the old one was, and the folder name appears in the carbon fiber section at the top]

Image One (Top Left): Click the menu item anywhere in the red section

Image Two (Top Right): When the link is clicked, the ID of that folder is saved, and another menu slides right

Image Three (Bottom Left): The new menu slides into where the old one was, and the folder name appears in the carbon fiber section at the top

When the new link (in image three) is clicked, not only does it load content in an area outside of the picture provided, but also records the ID of that LI clicked.

If anyone has any suggestions for getting this to only save the ID of the li clicked, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the code how you use `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: Hi @pktangyue Unfortunately I cant use event.stopPropagation() as once the ID has been saved, by this function, a subsequent ajax call is made. If i use stopPropagation, the ajax call doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `on()`, as `live()` is deprecated, and `e.target.id` will give you the ID of the element that was actually clicked :

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=folderLink_]', function(e){
    if (this===e.target) alert(e.target.id);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGTJs/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your help @adeneo Unfortunately the code you provided does the same action as the behaviour in the original post.
I have provided a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UGTJs/

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
alert($(this).attr('id');
------------------------^ Missing end braces.
```

Replace it with:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

---

Leaving this, your query is something to do with bubbling up of events. When you have the `li` inside another `li` with the same kind of event, then this problem occurs.

You need to use this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=folderLink_]', function(e){
    alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```

---

From your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGTJs/), add this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=folderLink_]', function(e){
    alert($(e.target).attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGTJs/1/).

Comment: Sorry, that was only a typo in the posting on stackoverflow, it has the closing brace in the actual code, I'll update the question.

Comment: @PhilCross Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Sorry again! This does the same action as described in the original post, however when clicking a nested li displays 'undefined' now :(
I appreciate your help nevertheless!
http://jsfiddle.net/UGTJs/

Comment: @PhilCross See my updated answer and see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UGTJs/1/

Comment: sorry, unfortunately, although this is nearly there, I can't return false or use stopPropagation() as I need a subsequent ajax call to take place :(

Comment: @PhilCross No issues. AJAX will work. Don't worry, as you are giving this at the end only. Check and then let us know..

Answer (score 1):

doing so will suffice

```
$('[id^=folderLink_]').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KTWnb/

Comment: BTW this is the way that the .click() is done http://api.jquery.com/click/
edited the answer and replaced it by your code , now it works just great

Comment: glad that it helped ;) never forget about propagation ! ;P

Comment: Sorry, although this does work in jsfiddle, and is nearly there, I cant use 'return false' or stopPropagation() as an ajax call needs to be performed after saving the ID of the element clicked :( I'll +1 the answer though as its nearly there!

Comment: please tell me the following . first that you have removed the `alert()` before the ajax request , second that the `e.stopPropagation()` is at the end of the click function .. if these both are done , then there will be no way that this wont work ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[id^=folderLink_]').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

`e.stopPropagation()` will prevent it from bubbling it up the DOM tree.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JYcZS/